# How to configure number of shards per cluster in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't understand the configuration of shards in ES.
I have few questions about sharding in ES:

1. The number of primary shards is configured through `index.number_of_shards` parameter, right?

   So, it means that the number of shards are configured per index.
   If so, if I have 2 indexes, then I will have 10 shards on the node ?
2. Assuming I have one node (Node 1) that configured with 3 shards and 1 replica.
   Then, I create a new node (Node 2), in the same cluster, with 2 shards.
   So, I assume I will have replica only to two shards, right?

   In addition, what happens in case Node 1 is down, how the cluster "knows" that it should have 3 shards instead of 2? Since I have only 2 shards on Node 2, then it means that I lost the data of one of the shards in Node 1 ?

Answer (score 9):

So first off I'd start reading about indexes, primary shards, replica shards and nodes to understand the differences:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/glossary.html

This is a pretty good description:

> 2.3 Index Basics
>
> The largest single unit of data in elasticsearch is an index. Indexes
>   are logical and physical partitions of documents within elasticsearch.
>   Documents and document types are unique per-index. Indexes have no
>   knowledge of data contained in other indexes. From an operational
>   standpoint, many performance and durability related options are set
>   only at the per-index level. From a query perspective, while
>   elasticsearch supports cross-index searches, in practice it usually
>   makes more organizational sense to design for searches against
>   individual indexes.
>
> Elasticsearch indexes are most similar to the ‘database’ abstraction
>   in the relational world. An elasticsearch index is a fully partitioned
>   universe within a single running server instance. Documents and type
>   mappings are scoped per index, making it safe to re-use names and ids
>   across indexes. Indexes also have their own settings for cluster
>   replication, sharding, custom text analysis, and many other concerns.
>
> Indexes in elasticsearch are not 1:1 mappings to Lucene indexes, they
>   are in fact sharded across a configurable number of Lucene indexes, 5
>   by default, with 1 replica per shard. A single machine may have a
>   greater or lesser number of shards for a given index than other
>   machines in the cluster. Elasticsearch tries to keep the total data
>   across all indexes about equal on all machines, even if that means
>   that certain indexes may be disproportionately represented on a given
>   machine. Each shard has a configurable number of full replicas, which
>   are always stored on unique instances. If the cluster is not big
>   enough to support the specified number of replicas the cluster’s
>   health will be reported as a degraded ‘yellow’ state. The basic dev
>   setup for elasticsearch, consequently, always thinks that it’s
>   operating in a degraded state given that by default indexes, a single
>   running instance has no peers to replicate its data to. Note that this
>   has no practical effect on its operation for development purposes. It
>   is, however, recommended that elasticsearch always run on multiple
>   servers in production environments. As a clustered database, many of
>   data guarantees hinge on multiple nodes being available.

From here: http://exploringelasticsearch.com/modeling_data.html#sec-modeling-index-basics

When you create an index it you tell it how many primary and replica shards http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html. ES defaults to 5 primary shard and 1 replica shard per primary for a total of 10 shards.

These shards will be balanced over how many nodes you have in the cluster, provided that a primary and it's replica(s) cannot reside on the same node. So if you start with 2 nodes and the default 5 primary shards and 1 replica per primary you will get 5 shards per node. Add more nodes and the number of shards per node drops. Add more indexes and the number of shards per node increases.

In all cases the number of nodes must be 1 greater than the configured number of replicas. So if you configure 1 replica you should have 2 nodes so that the primary can be on one and the single replica on the other, otherwise the replicas will not be assigned and your cluster status will be Yellow. If you have it configured for 2 replicas which means 1 primary shard and 2 replica shards you need at least 3 nodes to keep them all separate. And so on.

Your questions can't be answered directly because they are based on incorrect assumptions about how ES works. You don't add a node with shards - you add a node and then ES will re-balance the existing shards across the entire cluster. Yes, you do have some control over this if you want but I would not do so until you are much more familiar with ES operations. I'd read up on it here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html and here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html and here: http://exploringelasticsearch.com/advanced_techniques.html#advanced-routing

From the last link:

> 8.1.1 How Elasticsearch Routing Works
>
> Understanding routing is important in large elasticsearch clusters. By
>   exercising fine-grained control over routing the quantity of cluster
>   resources used can be severely reduced, often by orders of magnitude.
>
> The primary mechanism through which elasticsearch scales is sharding.
>   Sharding is a common technique for splitting data and computation
>   across multiple servers, where a property of a document has a function
>   returning a consistent value applied to it in order to determine which
>   server it will be stored on. The value used for this in elasticsearch
>   is the document’s _id field by default. The algorithm used to convert
>   a value to a shard id is what’s known as a consistent hashing
>   algorithm.
>
> Maintaining good cluster performance is contingent upon even shard
>   balancing. If data is unevenly distributed across a cluster some
>   machines will be over-utilized while others will remain mostly idle.
>   To avoid this, we want as even a distribution of numbers coming out of
>   our consistent hashing algorithm as possible. Document ids hash well
>   generally because they are evenly distributed if they are either UUIDs
>   or monotonically increasing ids (1,2,3,4 …).
>
> This is the default approach, and it generally works well as it solves
>   the problem of evening out data across the cluster. It also means that
>   fetches for a single document only need to be routed to the shard that
>   document hashes to. But what about routing queries? If, for instance,
>   we are storing user history in elasticsearch, and are using UUIDs for
>   each piece of user history data, user data will be stored evenly
>   across the cluster. There’s some waste here, however, in that this
>   means that our searches for that user’s data have poor data locality.
>   Queries must be run on all shards within the index, and run against
>   all possible data. Assuming that we have many users we can likely
>   improve query performance by consistently routing all of a given
>   user’s data to a single shard. Once the user’s data has been
>   so-segmented, we’ll only need to execute across a single shard when
>   performing operations on that user’s data.

Comment: This seems to be a common misunderstanding. The topic of replicas is totally separate from the topic of how many shards you should have. Your number of shards should be greater than or equal to the number of nodes. Then, you should create enough replicas to achieve your desired amount of failover. For example, for three nodes you would have thee shards. Then, you would assign either 1 or 2 replicas. With 2 replicas all but one node could go down and you'd still have a complete shard set to keep you cluster running. With 1 replica, only one node could go down at a time before your cluster dies.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, the number of shards is per index. So if you had 2 indexes, each with 5 shards, then yes, you would have a total of 10 shards distributed across all your nodes.
2. The number of shards is unrelated to the number of nodes in the cluster. If you have 3 shards and one node, obviously all 3 shards will reside on that one node. However, if you then add an additional node, more shards are not magically created and you can't specify that a certain number of shards should reside on that new node. Rather, the existing shards are distributed as evenly as possible across all nodes resulting in one node with 2 shards and one node with 1 shard, for a total of 3. If you added a third node, then each node would house 1 shard for a total of 3. In other words, the number of shards is fixed and doesn't scale as you add more nodes.

As to your final question, it's based on a false premise, so it's difficult to answer. Rather, lets take the example of above of three shards and two nodes. In that setup, one node will house 2 shards and one node will house 1 shard. If either of those nodes go down, your cluster goes down, because neither has a complete set of shards. The first node is missing 1 shard and the second node is missing 2. This is where replicas come in. By adding replicas, you can ensure that each node ends up with a full set of shards. For example, if you added 1 replica in the above scenario, then the first node would have 2 active shards and 1 replica of the third that lives on the other node. The second node would have 1 active shard and 1 replica each of the two that live on the first. As a result, if either node went down, the cluster can merely activate the replicas and still continue working.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, the number of shards is configured per index. It is a static operation and should be done while creating an index. If you want to change the number of shards at a later point of time, you have to reindex the document again and takes time.

2) The number of shards don't depend on number of nodes in you cluster. Lets say you are a book seller website. You have 100 books to sell. your website have an elastic cluster with 3 nodes. you create a book index with 5 shards. Each and very shard contains 20 books. 2 shards will reside on node1, 2 shards will reside in node2 and 1 shard will reside in node3. now let's say node 2 has gone down. But, still we have 2 shards in node 1 and 1 shard in node 3. Querying elastic search will still return the data on node 1 and node 3. i.e, 60 books data will still be available. 40 books data is lost.

But, the overall cluster status will be red meaning cluster is partially functioning, but somedata is not available.

To make the system fault tolerant you can configure replicas. By default elasticsearch makes one replica of each shard. So in this case if the default configuration is not over written the copy of 2 shards on node 2 will be replicated either on node 1 or node 3 and they become the primary shards when node 2 is not available. So all the data is available even when node 2 is down.

in this case the overall cluster health will be yellow, meaning cluster is still functional. But some nodes are lost.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1)** yes you will have 10 shards fr 2 index with 5 shards.

**Answer 2)** I think you confused with shards and index.

Shards are split piece for index not for node.

If you create a index with 3 shards and 1 replica.

You will get 3 primary shard and 3 replica shards.

If you start new node the shards will be balanced with new node.So you will have 3 shard in old node and 3 shards in new node.

If old node fails you will survive with new node data.It will have exact copy of old node.

To understand basic concepts of elasticsearch [refer](http://technyvorous.wordpress.com/elastic-search/)

HOpe it helps..!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand is how the new node has 3 shards ?
Can I configure it to have 2 shards, like my example ?
If yes, then how it will work ? 
In addition, does it mean that if I have two indexes then I will have 6 primary shards and 6 replicas ?

Comment: Because that part is incorrect. The total number of shards is evenly distributed over the total number of nodes. If you have 3 nodes and 3 shards, each node will have 1 shard, *not* 3.

Comment: i meant totally 2 nodes..and 6 shards.. it ll distribute 6 shards into 3 each per node..!

Comment: I see, but you should make it clearer that not all three shards on each node are active. You'll have one node with 2 active shards and 1 replica and one node with 1 active shard and 2 replicas.